# Assembly - lea and arithmetic

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, pointer-arithmetic

#### Context:

- Assembly
- gas
- x86_64

My assembly is a *bit* rusty and I try to make it good again.

The C code showing the intent:

```
void ask_me(int * data){

    (*data)++;

}
```

It is deliberately stupid, but fits the context.

My working assembly :

```
_ask_me:
   addq $1, (%rdi)
   ret
```

#### Question:

I would like to use the `lea` instruction, as a training.
But I couldn't make it work:

```
_ask_me:
    leaq 1(%rdi), %rdi

    ret
```

Worst:

```
_ask_me:
    movq (%rdi), %rcx
    leaq 1(%rcx), %rdi

    ret
```

Could you remind me how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original assembly reads and writes from/to memory. That is:

```
addq $1, (%rdi)
```

performs the operation:

```
*(rdi) += 1
```

You cannot achieve the same thing with `LEA`, because `LEA` stores the result *in a register*, not in memory. So you can use it do to `rdi += 1` (as in your first attempt), but not `*(rdi) += 1`.

Comment: to bad for me :) I didn't remember properly its use.

Answer (score 1):

`inc` can take a memory operand, if you're trying to save insn bytes.  Normally the point of doing math with `lea` is the non-destructive operation (result in a different reg from the source(s)), and/or combining a shift, add, and add-immediate.

```
lea 17(%rax, %rbx, 4), %rcx   # rcx = 17 + rax + rbx*4
```

replaces 4 instructions (including a mov).

Comment: I was interested in the "no flags is touched" thing :)

Comment: Ah right, math without affecting flags is another major use for `LEA`.  With macro-fusion between ALU ops and `jcc`, it's usually best to put the branch next to the op that sets flags, but sometimes there's another dependent calculation you want done before the branch.